# Can't retrieve all XML data with python

Tags: python, xml-parsing

Hello I'm trying to get all the data from an XML database and get it into a SQLite database to work with it but got stuck at the xml straction.

The database is in the next URL:
"https://sdmx.data.unicef.org/ws/public/sdmxapi/rest/data/UNICEF,MNCH,1.0/.MNCH_PNEUCARE......."

It have the next format:

```
<message:StructureSpecificData xmlns:ss="http...">
  <message:Header>...
  </message:Header>
  <message:DataSet ss:dataScope="...">
    <Series REF_AREA="AFG" INDICATOR="MNCH_PNEUCARE" SEX="_T" AGE="Y0T4" AGE_AT_BIRTH="_T" WEALTH_QUINTILE="_T" RESIDENCE="R" MOTHER_EDUCATION="_T" DATA_SOURCE="MNCH_SRC_4" UNIT_MULTIPLIER="0" UNIT_MEASURE="PCNT" SUB_SECTOR="PNEU">
      <Obs TIME_PERIOD="2011" OBS_VALUE="59.2" OBS_STATUS="RP" OBS_CONF="F"/>
    </Series>
    <Series REF_AREA="...">
      <Obs TIME_PERIOD="..."/>
    </Series>
    <Series REF_AREA="...">
      <Obs TIME_PERIOD="..."/>
    </Series>
  </message:DataSet>
</message:StructureSpecificData>
```

After a lot of research I actually could retrieve the "Series" attributes as a Dictionary and in this piece of code I'm just showing you the extraction of "REF_AREA" from that dictionary.
I've been searching and coding without success for a week now but can't find how to retrieve the data of the "Obs" attributes.

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import ssl

# Next code ignores SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = "https://sdmx.data.unicef.org/ws/public/sdmxapi/rest/data/UNICEF,MNCH,1.0/.MNCH_PNEUCARE......."
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

tree = ET.parse(html)
root = tree.getroot()
for x in root[1]:
    z=x.attrib
    w=z.get('REF_AREA',0)
```

I'm open to know your thoughts on how you would approach the problem.

My full code looks like this:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import ssl

# Next code ignores SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

conn = sqlite3.connect('Data.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

url = "https://sdmx.data.unicef.org/ws/public/sdmxapi/rest/data/UNICEF,MNCH,1.0/.MNCH_PNEUCARE......."

cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Unicef_Data
    (id INTEGER UNIQUE, Geographic_Area TEXT, Indicator TEXT, Sex TEXT, Current_Age TEXT, Residence TEXT, TIME_PERIOD INT, OBS_VALUE NUMERIC)''')

print("Retrieving", url)
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

tree = ET.parse(html)
root = tree.getroot()
y=0
for x in root[1]:
    z=x.attrib
    a=z.get('REF_AREA',0)
    b=z.get('INDICATOR',0)
    c=z.get('SEX',0)
    d=z.get('AGE',0)
    e=z.get('RESIDENCE',0)
    f=z.get('TIME_PERIOD',0)
    g=z.get('OBS_VALUE',0)
    y=y+1
    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Unicef_Data (id, Geographic_Area, Indicator, Sex, Current_Age, Residence, TIME_PERIOD, OBS_VALUE)
    VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )''', ( y, a, b, c, d, e, f, g))
    conn.commit()

conn.commit()
cur.close()
```

Thank you all for your comments.

Comment: You don't seem to be *doing* anything with what you've extracted that could be used to populate a database.

Comment: You are correct and it is because I've being printing "w" to see what I'm extracting before creating a database because I want to be certain of what am I retrieving.

Comment: Just posted my hole code for you to see that the "TIME_PERIOD" & "OBS_VALUE" are fields I need to retrieve but are the ones I cant find how to do it. Think it's because of the XML format that looks like if they were "Obs" attributes inside "Series" data.

Comment: You need to get the `Obs` *element* of each `Series` since that is the object that has the remaining *attributes* you want.